# Robotframework with Selenium2 Library-Select Frame is not readable?

Tags: robotframework

I have a simple command such as Selenium2Library.Select frame   id = 859762697  I run the test cases and in the logs I cannot see anywhere the Select Frame. Even if my id was wrong I would expect to see something like "cannot find the element". In my case there is nowhere Select Frame as keyword in the log file. I appreciate everyone's help

Here are the 3 lines of code  where the Select Frame keyword is sitting

```
Click Quiz1
    Selenium2Library.click element    css=a[jotid='wuid:gx:360a0a5966614f2d']
Select Frame 
    Selenium2Library.select frame    id = 859762697
Click correct answer 
    Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot
```

Here is the log . Notice that the keyword "Select Frame" between the test cases Click Quiz1 and Click correct Answer it doesn't exist. It's like it never run.

KEYWORD Click Quiz1

Start / End / Elapsed:
20161017 17:45:18.245 / 20161017 17:45:21.907 / 00:00:03.662
00:00:03.662
KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Click Element css=a[jotid='wuid:gx:360a0a5966614f2d']

Documentation:
Click element identified by `locator`.
Start / End / Elapsed:
20161017 17:45:18.245 / 20161017 17:45:21.907 / 00:00:03.662
17:45:18.245
INFO
Clicking element 'css=a[jotid='wuid:gx:360a0a5966614f2d']'.

00:00:01.255
KEYWORD Click correct answer

Start / End / Elapsed:
20161017 17:45:21.907 / 20161017 17:45:23.162 / 00:00:01.255
00:00:00.347
KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Capture Page Screenshot

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Are you expecting us to come over to your house to look at the code? :-)

Comment: Please read more carefully what I write. I state that I cannot see in the log file the Select Frame key word. I have also the line I run on my comment .  Selenium2Library.Select frame id = 859762697.  I think is very obvious that although I run a keyword I cannot find in the log even as a failure. So I cannot understand why this happen. I cannot explain it so I cannot see how else I could express it. I do not know why asked the last question. My code is already in my post.

Comment: Without seeing your code, the only thing we can guess at is that you are not calling `Select Frame` in your test, or are not running the test suite that you think you are running. Without seeing exactly what you are doing, all we can do is guess. As written, the answer to your question can only be "you're doing it wrong". If you need a better answer, you're going to have to ask a better question.

Comment: please don't post code in a comment. Your question has an "edit" link you can click to edit the question. You might also want to include a small portion of the log that shows the result of the keywords for this one test case.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I edit my original question based on your suggestions. I hope is better now.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Select Frame` is not indented, robot thinks that's the name of the next test case. For it to be treated as a keyword it needs to be indented like the line below it and the line above it.

I'm guessing everything you have in the question belongs to one test case, so it needs to look like this:

```
Click Quiz1
    Selenium2Library.click element    css=a[jotid='wuid:gx:360a0a5966614f2d']
    Select Frame 
    Selenium2Library.select frame    id = 859762697
    Click correct answer 
    Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot
```